# Upgrade Magento while keeping all order data, sales data, ect

Tags: upgrade

Is there a definitive way to upgrade Magento while keeping all order data, sales data, ect?

After setting up a staging environment and ensuring all extensions, ect. are working properly there will inevitably be orders placed, orders processed, ect. Is there a proper way to sync the data with the production installation?

An alternative way I've read about is to set up a staging area and essentially practice the upgrade while taking notes on all the fixes that need to be completed. Then put the site into maintenance mode and do the upgrade on in the production environment. Is this a viable solution?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade Magento you will keep all your old data

See the WIKI on the Magento site here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

It will layout the steps to upgrade your site. Remember always make a backup!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will of course keep all your data in tact, but requires downtime while doing the upgrade. Do you know of a way to not loose data while having no downtime?

Comment: You can either keep a version running side by side and re-enter orders, you can also use a module to export the orders from the live version to the upgrade version (Difference) Or you could do it at Midnight and put up a message that says you will be done

Answer (score 0):

If You are Going to upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.x.x then you can do it manually very easily by following step:

- Download latest magensto version (1.9.x.x)
- Unzip it
- now lets your current files are in old_files >> follow this command:

> cp -r path/to/magento/*  path/to/old_files/

When it is done set your `permissions for files again` and now you are all done.